# Trying to find matched md5 hash in folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to write the program to search for md5 hash files in ffile folder to match specific hash. Please help!

`import hashlib`

```
 from hashlib import md5
    hash_file = raw_input ()
    afile = open('ffile','rb')
    buf = afile.read ()
```

Comment: Kindly elaborate on the actual problem you are facing. See [ask] & [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
hash_to_find = '5c583fd40360fd039b3ac98387b77dbb'
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(i):
         with open(i,'rb') as f:
             for line in f:
                 if line.startswith(hash_to_find):
                     print(i)             
                     break
```